# Finding an integral using Bernoulli Numbers exponential generating function

Tags: calculus, generating-functions, gamma-function, riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

The following exponential generating function of the Bernoulli Numbers is the following:

$$\frac{t}{e^t-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \frac{t^n}{n!}$$
The following result, which is a well known special case of the Bose Integral:
$$\zeta(2)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$
Hence
$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1}dx$$
But, using the exponential generating function of the Bernoulli Numbers, one obtains:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1}dx=\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \frac{x^n}{n!}dx$$
Now, we can interchange the sum and the integral (As it is satisfying Tolleni & Fubini's Theorems), and finally obtain:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$, where x is taken from 0 to infinity.
It it easy to prove that the overall sum is equal to 0-Thus the question: Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Lol true, thanks. What a silly mistake

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $\frac{t}{e^t-1}$ in Bernouilli numbers gives the meromorphic continuation and the residue of the simple pole of $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$ at $1-k, k\ge 0$. To find $\zeta(2k)$ you need the residue theorem, or the functional equation, or some Fourier series tricks, or just $\frac{2i\pi}{e^{2i\pi z}-1}+\frac12=\sum_n \frac1{z-n}$ (looking at the Laurent series at $0$ of both sides).